# Summarizing dictionary with top two choices

Tags: python, dictionary

```
inventory = {'A':['Toy',3, 1000], 'B':['Toy',8, 1100], 
              'C':['Cloth',15, 1200], 'D':['Cloth',9, 1300], 
               'E':['Toy',11, 1400], 'F':['Cloth', 18, 1500], 'G':['Appliance', 300, 50]}
```

The alphabets are name of merchandise, the first field in the [] brackets are category of the merchandise, the second field in the [] brackets are price, the third are numbers sold.

I would like to get the top two most expensive (in price) merchandises for each category.  If I don’t have at least two merchandises in each category, I would drop it.  So I should have the following result.

```
inventorySummary = {'B':['Toy',8, 1100], 'E':['Toy',11, 1400], 
                     'C':['Cloth',15, 1200], 'F':['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
```

Could you help me what code I could use to facilitate this?  I need one that I could potentially use for not just top two priced items, but also top three or four priced items.  I will eventually use it against much bigger data set so if it could be more generic code that would be better.  Also I have a hard time understanding lambda expressions, if you choose to offer a code with lambda expression, could you please explain each part as to how it works so that I would be able to manipulate down the road for any changed needs.

I only have these modules available for my system:

bisect,
cmath,
collections,
datetime,
functools,
heapq,
itertools,
math,
numpy,
pandas,
pytz,
Queue,
random,
re,
scipy,
statsmodels,
sklearn,
talib,
time,
zipline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to create the groups:

```
from itertools import groupby

def summarize_inventory(inventory):
    # We use -price so that we are also sorting by descending price
    sort_key = lambda (code, (cat, price, sold)): (cat, -price)
    group_key = lambda (code, (cat, price, sold)): cat

    new_dict = {}
    sorted_inventory = sorted(inventory.iteritems(), key=sort_key)
    for cat, group in groupby(sorted_inventory, key=group_key):
        group = list(group)
        if len(group) > 1:
            for (code, item) in group[:2]:
                new_dict[code] = item
    return new_dict
```

### Example

```
>>> summarize_inventory(inventory)

{'B': ['Toy', 8, 1100],
 'C': ['Cloth', 15, 1200],
 'E': ['Toy', 11, 1400],
 'F': ['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
```

Comment: Never occurred to me you could pattern match like that in `sort_key` and `group_key`. Very nice!

Comment: This is a O(NlogN) solution; for each N elements in the input dictionary, N times log N steps need to be performed for the solution

Comment: Thanks enrico.bacis!  But, would it be hard to do the second highest price only?  So you get {'B': ['Toy', 8, 1100], 'C': ['Cloth', 15, 1200]}.  And keep the rest of the logic the same.  I would think you modify "for (code, item) in group[:2]:" part to something else.

Comment: @UjaeKang:this is super easy, use group[1:2] instead of group[:2]

Answer (score 1):

To get the top N of any series in the most efficient way possible, use the [`heapq` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py). You'll have to create a heap per category:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappushpop

def summarize_inventory(inventory, top_n=2):
    categories = {}
    for id, info in inventory.items():
        cat, _, sold = info
        heap = categories.setdefault(cat, [])
        if len(heap) < top_n:
            heap.append((sold, id, info))
            if len(heap) == top_n:
                heapify(heap)
        else:
            heappushpop(heap, (sold, id, info))

    # produce the final summary, only include categories with enough items
    return {id: info 
            for cat, heap in categories.items() if len(heap) == top_n
            for sold, id, info in heap}
```

The first loop builds the heaps up to size 2, heapifies those two items then uses the [`heapq.heappushpop()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) to add the next item to the heap and remove the so-far smallest in one step.

This is a O(NlogK) solution; for an input of size N (the number of keys in the input dictionary) and asking for the top K elements, the heap queue approach takes N times log K steps to produce the solution.

If you want to compare this to a O(NlogN) sorting solution (sort by category and price, then group by category), then this solution less time to complete as `N` grows. For getting the top two results for a given 1000 items, this takes 1.000 * 1 == 1.000 steps. Sorting would take 1.000 * 10 == 10.000 steps. For 1.000.000 inputs, that becomes 1 million vs. 1 billion steps, etc.

For your given inventory that produces:

```
>>> summarize_inventory(inventory)
{'B': ['Toy', 8, 1100], 'E': ['Toy', 11, 1400], 'D': ['Cloth', 9, 1300], 'F': ['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{'B': ['Toy', 8, 1100],
 'D': ['Cloth', 9, 1300],
 'E': ['Toy', 11, 1400],
 'F': ['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
```

The function works for any top N you might care to produce:

```
>>> summarize_inventory(inventory, 3)
{'A': ['Toy', 3, 1000], 'C': ['Cloth', 15, 1200], 'B': ['Toy', 8, 1100], 'E': ['Toy', 11, 1400], 'D': ['Cloth', 9, 1300], 'F': ['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
>>> summarize_inventory(inventory, 1)
{'E': ['Toy', 11, 1400], 'G': ['Appliance', 300, 50], 'F': ['Cloth', 18, 1500]}
```

Answer (score 0):

enrico.bacis beat me to a [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) solution, but here's my version if it helps you out (I tried to do it FP style):

```
def summarize_inventory(inventory, top_n=2):
    sort_key = lambda (id, (category, price, sold)): (category, price)
    group_key = lambda (id, (category, price, sold)): category

    # items in inventory grouped by their category
    items_by_category = (
        (category, list(items))
        for category, items in itertools.groupby(
            sorted(inventory.iteritems(), key=sort_key),
            group_key
        )
    )

    # the top_n items from each category if there are >= top_n items
    inventory_summary = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        items[-1 * top_n:]
        for category, items in items_by_category
        if len(items) >= top_n
    ))

    return inventory_summary
```